# How to visualize a layer onto a map with R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, shapefile, r-sf

I am trying to produce a map which would visualize the `lu_effic` on my map. With the current codes I can visualize the map and the `lu_effic` category, but they are not layered on each other. I would like to `fill` the map with `lu_effic` colors. I tried with `aes` to add `fill` in `geom_sf(data = shp_dt)` but didn't work. The `geom_polygon()` also showed error, as the shape file data is a `sf` format. It has geometry column instead of longitude and latitude columns separately. Hence, failed to run `aes (x= long, y=lat)`. I need to `fill` the map with `lu_effic` colors and other necessary visualization elements. Would anybody kindly assist me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

**The data frame `urb_dtf` is here**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mZOkMTLx830oPaqtg9TVpg0OTP5fGzcR/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114933701557583416369&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
urb_dtf
     dtafil.GCPNT_LAT dtafil.GCPNT_LON    lu_effic          dtafil.UC_NM_MN
1          26.23825         88.40822  2.49722588                   Atwari
2          26.03490         88.44599  1.30779927               Thakurgaon
3          26.33849         88.55293  4.41597618               Panchagarh
4          25.86100         88.36024  0.60699713                  Pirganj
5          24.94617         88.21594  0.15688455                     Asia
6          26.39944         88.96166  1.70447128                     Asia
7          25.85807         88.65385  4.35869046                      N/A
8          24.61404         88.23778  0.69757530          Chapainawabganj
9          25.62459         88.62559  0.70376589                 Dinajpur
10         26.34469         89.01786 -0.78882643                  Patgram
11         25.93154         88.85591  1.17247204               Nilphamari
12         25.79222         88.89938  0.53713622                  Saidpur
13         24.44356         88.34488 21.83406438                 Godagari
14         25.67936         89.05180  0.94306324                Bodorganj
15         24.41426         88.61983  0.67571401                 Rajshahi
16         25.10153         89.02355  9.89191877                Joypurhat
17         24.80587         88.95890  1.26512380                  Naogaon
18         24.37298         88.76614  0.43754723                Baneshwar
19         23.78359         88.63357  0.74975530                 Meherpur
20         24.41677         88.99007  0.82625124          à¦¨à¦¾à¦Ÿà§‹à¦°
21         25.69513         89.60984  1.43875426                   Ulipur
22         24.94282         89.37863  1.15731210                   Bogura
23         25.32976         89.53690  1.28528943                Gaibandha
24         23.63560         88.83938  0.88394331                Chuadanga
25         24.08493         89.09479  0.36944300                  Ishurdi
26         23.75310         88.94598  0.52944470                Alamdanga
27         23.90058         89.10053  0.68007198                 Barkhada
28         24.65859         89.44197  1.51617122                    Bogra
29         24.01567         89.26079  0.71299373                    Pabna
30         23.86184         89.15752  0.82472321                  Alampur
31         24.41254         89.64289  0.95057900                Sirajganj
32         23.40571         89.01174  0.69460150               Kotchadpur
33         23.04288         88.89597  0.75806861                     Asia
34         23.54037         89.17593  0.61603886                Jhenaidah
35         23.40988         89.13477  1.10069949 à¦•à¦¾à¦²à§€à¦—à¦žà§\u008dà¦œ
36         24.96816         89.97172  0.46869564                 Jamalpur
37         23.16668         89.20843  0.52640165                  Jessore
38         23.48845         89.42102  1.09687780                   Magura
39         24.32668         89.94591  0.82200687                  Tangail
40         24.76605         90.25557  0.56361005               Muktagacha
41         22.84015         89.55533 -1.26805716                   Khulna
42         23.58577         89.83287  1.35248758                 Faridpur
43         24.74904         90.38985  0.17224254               Mymensingh
44         23.84481         90.00978  0.95263604                Manikgonj
45         24.53342         90.34734  0.46884662                  Trishal
46         23.80705         90.40166  0.17146435                    Dhaka
47         23.91039         90.06940  0.25197463                   Jaigir
48         24.54544         90.42188  0.26382334                   Rampur
49         24.42903         90.38683  0.77181766                  Bhaluka
50         24.49606         90.49881  0.32848142                Gafargaon
51         23.01082         89.82701 -2.48743996                Gopalganj
52         22.66161         89.77432 -0.26417887                 Bagerhat
53         24.87865         90.72984  0.02135679                Netrokona
54         23.10274         90.17751 -2.59794615                Madaripur
55         24.41027         90.81461  0.29627310              Kishoreganj
56         24.57433         90.89773  0.40133470                   Tarail
57         23.21486         90.33779  1.49758668               Shariatpur
58         23.55846         90.60338  0.84538204                      N/A
59         24.05720         90.98408  0.15528478             Brahmanbaria
60         23.88657         90.73217  0.33951829                      N/A
61         23.55013         90.66072  1.08523717                  Gazaria
62         23.93776         90.86446  0.26901075                      N/A
63         23.69415         90.83184  0.35016879                    Homna
64         22.70696         90.35247 -0.89130028                  Barisal
65         23.14673         90.80557  0.57463630                 Chandpur
66         25.06408         91.40035  0.13625843       Sunamganj District
67         23.46517         90.78352  0.75471736                      N/A
68         23.80230         90.97777  0.18687093                Nabinagar
69         23.89096         91.03594  0.05931816                  Shibpur
70         24.06237         91.17975  0.09915729          Shahbazpur Town
71         22.99137         90.86482  0.19705905               Lakshmipur
72         22.67565         90.65828  1.14616972                    Bhola
73         24.38139         91.41250  0.16456846                 Habiganj
74         24.87859         91.90338  0.11481848                   Sylhet
75         24.49782         91.78539  0.13333066              Moulvibazar
76         24.33299         91.73140  0.20055411               Sreemangal
77         24.82160         92.16267  0.18369562               Beanibazar
78         23.00552         91.40018  0.53240186                     Feni
79         22.43880         91.82426  0.05366313               Chattogram
80         23.10985         91.98522  0.13909249             Khagrachhari
81         22.52012         91.92949  0.05425749                   Raujan
82         21.75023         92.05997  0.11659127                 Chakaria
83         22.20431         92.21605  0.08462762                Bandarban
84         21.43620         92.02313  0.07814110                     Ramu
85         20.86985         92.29864  0.17803279                   Teknaf
```

**The shape file link**: https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/BGD_adm.zip
The Zip file is available at DIVA-GIS (a popular platform to download shape file).  ***DIVA-GIS-> free spatial data -> country level data***

The codes I ran are as follows:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)


    urb_dt= read.csv("GHS_STAT_V1_2_BGD.csv")
    urb_dtf= data.frame(dtafil$GCPNT_LAT, dtafil$GCPNT_LON, lu_effic, dtafil$UC_NM_MN)
    dput(urb_dtf)   
      
    shp_dt= st_read("bgd_admbnda_adm3_bbs_20201113.shp")
    str(shp_dt)
    dput(shp_dt)

ggplot()+ geom_sf(data = shp_dt)+ 
    geom_polygon(data = urb_dtf, aes(dtafil.GCPNT_LON, dtafil.GCPNT_LAT, group = lu_effic, fill = lu_effic))
```

Finally, I get the following image. But I would like to fill the map with the colors of `lu_effic`.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPnmj.png)

Comment: Hi Kibria, welcome to SO. Please can you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I suggest using `dput`. If you don't know how it works have a look at `?dput`

Comment: Hi Robin, I have added `dput` of my data frame. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: I can't see it in your post. As an FYI, I do not generally click on links people post on SO (and I know others have a similar policy), so i can't see if you've copied the data into one of the links you shared. You should edit and paste it into your post wrapped inside code delimiters, i.e. these \```

Comment: I have added the data. But the shape file is huge to put in `dput` function. It is available in free shape file download site DIVA-GIS. COUNTRY: Bangladesh. I dont know how to add the file here. Let me know if can do it in anyway. This is first time at SO, things are new to me.

Comment: I think combing the files together with a common key is the first step. `new_sf <- original_sf %>% left_join(cool_data)` Then you can try something like `ggplot + geom_sf(data=new_sf, aes(fill = cool_stat))`.